# Equidistant points from all 3 lines

Tags: geometry

Two parallel lines m,n intersected by line r, how many equidistant points can we get from all 3 lines?

I was solving the problem like this: drawing two parallel line and take a traversals r, then taking perpendicular from the line r. Not sure about the process and number of intersects.
The problem space is 2D.

Comment: Are you talking in 2D or 3D? For 2D you have 2 points, for 3D you have an infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets call our parallel lines $l, m$ and the transversal is $r$

$r$ creates angles where it intersects $l.$

If we construct the angle bisectors then points on the angle bisectors are equidistant from both $r$ and $l.$

Similarly between $r$ and $m$ we can construct the angle bisectors.

How many angle bisectors have we constructed, how many points of intersection are there?

Finally midway between $l$ and $m$ is a line parallel to both equidistant from both.

Where does this intersect the angle bisectors we have created.  How many places are all 3 intersecting?
[image]

Comment: Give me a visulized form. The space is 2D.

Comment: @YeasirMohammadAkib You really should be able to do these constructions yourself.  But, I am in a generous mood.

Comment: Thanks for your generous help, so the answer is 2.